TYPO3 - Render extension plugin output via Typoscript
I'm using TYPO3 13.1.1 and I delevoped a custom extension in order to display on the front-end side some stuff generated by one of my extension Controller.
-> My extension was installed via Composer, and is displayed in the Extension back-end tab.
-> For the moment, I just need to output a "Hello World!" via a plugin
What I see on the front-end : Error "Oops, an error occurred"
My ProductSpaceController.php:
<?php

namespace Company\Controller;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\ActionController;

class ProductSpaceController extends ActionController
{
    public function testAction()
    {
        return 'Hello World';
    }
}

My ext_localconf.php:
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

use MyCompany\Controller\ProductSpaceController;
use TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility;

defined('TYPO3') or die('Access denied.');

ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin
(
    'company',
    'displaymatrice',
    [
        ProductSpaceController::class => 'test',
    ],
    [
        ProductSpaceController::class => 'test',
    ]
);

My Configuration/Services.yaml:
services:
  _defaults:
    autowire: true
    autoconfigure: true
    public: false

  Company\:
    resource: '../Classes/*'

My typoscript:
lib.testoutput = USER_INT // I also tried COA, USER
lib.testoutput < tt_content.list.20.company_displaymatrice

When I try to display in fluid, I get the error:
<f:cObject typoscriptObjectPath="lib.testoutput" />

PS: I have other "lib.xxx" that already work (for my top menu, my footer menu, my breadcrumb, my lang switcher etc...)

This should help you:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-typoscript/main/en-us/ContentObjects/Extbaseplugin/Index.html#example

Nope. EXTBASEPLUGIN is exactly, what is automatically in `tt_content.list.20.company_displaymatrice. So it does not matter if you write these lines on your own, or if you copy them from an existing block ;-)

Your so right. :-) Didn't know that. You never stop learning.

As Julian Hofmann mentioned above tt_content.list.20.company_displaymatrice already contains the needed EXTBASEPLUGIN object.
So you don't need this line in your TypoScript:
lib.testoutput = USER_INT // I also tried COA, USER
Since TYPO3 12 it's mandatory, that controller actions returns an instance of ResponseInterface. See here:
https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-coreapi/main/en-us/ExtensionArchitecture/Extbase/Reference/Controller/ActionController.html#actions
So your action needs to look like this:
public function testAction()
{
    return $this->htmlResponse('<p>Hello World</p>');
}


Either activate the error output as described by julian Hofmann or take a look in var/log/typo3_*.log and post the error that is logged there when calling the frontend.

Your solution fix my issue. Thanks!

The Ooops message is intentionally not very detailed. However, you can configure TYPO3 to become a little more talkative (during development or on the development-server).
Set the ApplicationContext to “Development”.
E.g. via htaccess file
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev\.example\.com$
RewriteRule .? - E=TYPO3_CONTEXT:Development]

More details (and other possibilities for setting) are explained e.g.
Make use of the TYPO3 Application Context
With a more detailed error message, you may be able to get further yourself - otherwise, others will be able to help you better.

Solution from @Mogens did fix my problem. But thank you for the advice, indeed it would help me to have a better understanding next time
